# Error getting the inputstream from an URL (XML file on the web server)

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a xml file as a stream to parse it after that. But I'm getting this error:

> ERROR : missing parameters, action:, objectType:, objectTable:,
>   objectId:

With this error, the xml file is like:

```xml
    <ERROR>
    <STATUS>ko</STATUS>
    <OBJECT_TYPE/>
    <OBJECT_TABLE/>
    <OBJECT_ID/>
    <APP_PATH/>
    <FILE_CONTENT/>
    <FILE_EXTENSION/>
    <ERROR>
    missing parameters, action:editObject, objectType:, objectTable:, objectId:
    </ERROR>
    <END_MESSAGE/>
    </ERROR>
```

But when I access the actual link on my browser, I'm getting the right file:

```xml
    <SUCCESS>
    <STATUS>ok</STATUS>
    <OBJECT_TYPE>resource</OBJECT_TYPE>
    <OBJECT_TABLE>res_version_business</OBJECT_TABLE>
    <OBJECT_ID>206</OBJECT_ID>
    <APP_PATH>start</APP_PATH>
    <FILE_CONTENT>UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA5en1zywEAAGMIAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAA</FILE_CONTENT>
    <FILE_EXTENSION>docx</FILE_EXTENSION>
    <ERROR/>
    <END_MESSAGE/>
    </SUCCESS>
```

Here is my code:

```java
    public void sendHttpRequest(String theUrl, String postRequest) throws Exception {

        URL UrlOpenRequest = new URL(theUrl);
        System.out.println("UrlOpenRequest: "+ theUrl);
        HttpURLConnection HttpOpenRequest =  (HttpURLConnection) 
        UrlOpenRequest.openConnection();
        HttpOpenRequest.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/xml");
        //HttpOpenRequest.setDoInput(true);
        HttpOpenRequest.setDoOutput(true);
        HttpOpenRequest.setRequestMethod("POST");
        HttpOpenRequest.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/xml");  

        if (!"none".equals(postRequest)) {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
            OutputStreamWriter(HttpOpenRequest.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("fileContent=" + this.fileContentTosend + "&fileExtension=" + this.fileExtension);
            writer.flush();
        } else {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
            OutputStreamWriter(HttpOpenRequest.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("foo=bar");
            writer.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("INPUT STREAM: "+HttpOpenRequest.getInputStream().available());

        this.parse_xml(HttpOpenRequest.getInputStream());
        HttpOpenRequest.disconnect();
    }
```

Any idea about the cause of this error?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming problem. You are probably sending different requests from browser (when you test the URL) and from code (application). One idea: it says that you miss some parameters, maybe those parameters are sent via http headers, so try to find those headers for the url you trigger from browser and if that is the case set them also for the request sent from the application.

Or if possible share the URL so we can take a look at it.

Comment: The URL I test on the browser is the same as the one sent from the application, I copy and past it on the browser and it works. That's why I'm confused. Here is the URL: `http://example.com/docs/modules/content/applet_controller.php/xml?action=editObject&objectType=resource&objectTable=res_version_business&objectId=206`

Comment: When u open from browser the HTTP method is default to GET, whereas in your code u are using POST, try to change that and see if that works

Comment: Even with GET method I have the same error.

Comment: It would have been quite easy to tell the problem if ur URL was live. Try to use postman and see if that works, then you can copy the HTTP request from there and share, or else copy the HTTP request from browser dev tools

Comment: I didn't get your idea. Can you please explain more?

Comment: in chrome dev tools  (ctrl+shift+i) , go to network tab, enter the url in the browser address bar , u would see a request in network tab. Right click that and copy as cUrl  bash, paste here whatever u get

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see what you get :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception
  {
    new Main();
  }

  public Main()
  {
    try
    {
      String myUrl = "http://google.com/"; // change your url here

      String results = doHttpUrlConnectionAction(myUrl);
      System.out.println(results);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      //whatever error
    }
  }

  private String doHttpUrlConnectionAction(String desiredUrl)
  throws Exception
  {
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    try
    {
      url = new URL(desiredUrl);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

      connection.setReadTimeout(30*1000);
      connection.connect();

      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
      }
      return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
      if (reader != null)
      {
        try
        {
          reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is giving me this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ERROR><STATUS>ko</STATUS><OBJECT_TYPE/><OBJECT_TABLE/><OBJECT_ID/><APP_PATH/><FILE_CONTENT/><FILE_EXTENSION/><ERROR>missing parameters, action:, objectType:, objectTable:, objectId:</ERROR><END_MESSAGE/></ERROR>`
I think that the problem is that I lose the authentification when I launch the jnlp file that execut my java code. Is there a way to transfer logins of user authentificated automatically to the jnlp file?